# Is it possible to install Linux on HP Touchpad?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

Is it possible to install Linux on the HP Touchpad which has WebOS on it?  Secondly, what would I need to do specifically to get it on there?

Comment: [WebOS is Linux based](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/news-media/news/2011/06/pc-world-hp-touchpad%E2%80%99s-best-feature-linux). However, you can supposedly [run Andoid on an HP Touch](http://www.precentral.net/android-dual-booted-pre-hardware)(with a bit of black magic). Happy hacking ;)

Comment: See this....http://liliputing.com/2011/08/hp-touchpad-afterlife-hackers-bringing-android-ubuntu-to-hps-tablet.html

Comment: Take a look at [webOS Internals](http://www.webos-internals.org/).  It is super easy to access the the Linux subsystem of your device.